# Why would Pence need to withdraw?

Tags: united-states, election

The [NYT article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/07/15/us/politics/mike-pence-donald-trump-vice-president.html?_r=0) on a potential Trump/Pence ticket states:

> The delay has the potential to complicate a partnership with Mr. Pence, who must file papers in Indiana by noon on Friday withdrawing from his re-election campaign in order for Republicans to field a new candidate for the race.

Why is this the case? Joe Biden, for example, ran parallel campaigns in 2008, and if Obama had not been elected, he would have (presumably) remained in the Senate.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know about this cut-off, but that explains why Trump announced it via Twitter even after the press conference got moved.  If Pence had filed without being announced, people would have figured it out anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delaware law allowed for the parallel campaigns.  Indiana law differs.
[CNN says](http://www.cnn.com/2016/07/07/politics/mike-pence-donald-trump-vp/) Indiana law has a prohibition on dual campaigns past the cutoff date.